# consulta con rangos de fechas y valores de un mes

Tags: php, mysql

En mi app tengo una tabla como esta:

### INACTIVITY:

```
id      user_id         start         end          comment
 265       2         29-04-2017    05-05-2017   Vacaciones
 356       2         07-04-2017    10-04-2017   Baja Enfermedad
 455      15         24-04-2017    24-08-2017   Maternidad
```

Se trata de incidencias que tienen los trabajadores, que no le permiten trabajar. Para generar un parte de ausencias, necesito sacar las inactividades del MES y AÑO que me indiquen.

Para simplificar, he puesto ejemplo de los meses de mayo, junio, julio y agosto.

- si me indican el mes 3, no hay incidencias
- si me indican mes 4, tengo tres incidencias, una del usuario 15 y otras del usuario 2
- si me indican el mes 5, tengo dos incidencias (la 265 y la 455, la 365 solo esta en el mes 4).
- si me indican el mes 6, 7 u 8, debería salir solo la incidencia 15.

Actualmente, lo que hago es:

- cojo el valor de año y mes,
- calculo los dias de ese mes.
- obtengo $inicio y $fin (siendo $inicio = 1/mes/año y $fin = dias_mes/mes/año)

Con eso, ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

**Select * from Inactivity i
where i.start >= $inicio AND i.end <=$fin**

Con esta consulta solo obtengo las que estan dentro del mes, pero no aquellas que empezaron en el mes anterior Y continuan en el mes, o las que empiezan en el mes y continuan en el mes siguiente. Ok. Tengo que cambiar la consulta.

He probado a cambiar la consulta a

```
select * from Inactivity i
where (i.start >=$inicio AND i.end <= $fin) 
OR (  ($inicio between i.start and i.end) AND ($fin between i.start and i.end) )
```

Es decir, aquellas inactividades que esten en el rango de fechas, o aquellas que la fecha de inicio este entre inicio y fin de la incidencia  y la fecha de fin entre inicio y fin de incidencia. Pero los resultados son los mismos.

No veo como hacer esta consulta. Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Con hacer un OR entre $inicio y $fin tendria que valerte.

```
SELECT * FROM Inactivity i 
WHERE $inicio BETWEEN start AND end 
OR $fin BETWEEN start AND end
```

Con esto te traes los registros si el el 1/mes/año esta entre el start and end o el finMes/mes/año esta entre el start and end

Comment: Correcto. Eso me devuelve los datos de los casos de extremo. Pero me ha surgido un caso que no coje, y es cuando la fecha de fin es el dia 1/mes/año. La inclusion del BETWEEN deberia aceptarlo, pero no se por que no lo hace. Seguire investigando.

Comment: He visto hace un rato un comentario tuyo, pero ya no esta. Lo has borrado?  Tenias razon, estoy usando datetime completo y no tenia en cuenta la hora inicial con 00:00:00 y la hora fin de 23:59:59. Muchas gracias, ya he corregido la solución.

Comment: Si, la he borrado porque pense que te habia entendido mal y no iba a funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de obtener los datos por mes y/o año es con `date_format`, aquí te dejo un ejemplo sencillo, también prodías utilizar `between` para la condición del mes.

```
SELECT * FROM inactivity i
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(start,'%Y') = 2017
AND DATE_FORMAT(start,'%m') <= '04'
AND DATE_FORMAT(end,'%m') >= '04'
```

Comment: En esa consulta tienes 3 variables (año, mes inicio y mes fin )cuando el solo tiene 2 (año y mes)

Comment: Mes de inicio y mes de fin pueden ser iguales, o en el caso de que quiera ver en varios meses distintos, por eso le doy la alternativa en el ejemplo.

Comment: No, en su problema mes inicio y mes de fin son siempre iguales. Y en ese caso tu query no funciona pues solo se trae los registros que inicien y acaben en ese mes cuando lo que quiere es aquellos que cuyo periodo tenga algun dia en el mes indicado. Tampoco funcionaria si es entre varios meses porque solo traeria los que inicia y acaban en ese periodo.

Comment: Por ejemplo para el mes 4, tu query retorna 1 unico valor mientras que la que necesita deberia retornar 3.

Comment: Tenías razón Lithorell, puse al revés >/<, me despisté, corregido

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

al final me he decantado mas por la solución de Lithorell. He tenido que modificar una cosa que no me gusta, pero que no consigo completar.

Se ha dado otro caso que en principio la consulta deberia cojerlo sin problemas, pero no lo hace. Es el siguiente:

```
id      user_id         start         end          comment
471      18           24-04-2017    1-05-2017     Vacaciones
```

Es decir, el caso de que la fecha de fin de incidencia sea el dia 1 del mes que buscamos.

Al final, la consulta ha quedado asi:

```
SELECT * FROM Inactivity i 
WHERE (i.start BETWEEN $inicio AND $find) 
   OR (end BETWEEN $inicio AND $fin) 
   OR (start >= $inicio AND end <= $fin )
   OR (end = $diauno )
```

El ultimo OR  (end = $diauno) hace referencia a ese 1 del mes en curso. No entiendo por que, pero si la fecha de fin es el 1/mes/año la consulta NO coje dicha incidencia.

Se que es una ñapa mu mala, pero como os digo, si no la pongo no coje el valor. He revisado los < y >, no fuera que faltara el caso de <=  para añadirlo, pero no entiendo por que.

**EDITO:**

Localizado el fallo a raiz de un comentario de Lithorell. Efectivamente, estoy utilizando datetimes, con hh:mm:ss. y precisamente el valor que no cogia es por mi calculo de $inicio y $fin, que son datetimes con la hora ACTUAL. Fallo mio.

Ahora corrijo el calculo del $inicio y $fin asi:

```
$start = new \Datetime($start->format('Y-m-d'));
$end = new \Datetime($end->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59'));
```

Y la consulta queda ahora:

```
SELECT * FROM Inactivity i 
WHERE (i.start BETWEEN $inicio AND $find) 
   OR (end BETWEEN $inicio AND $fin) 
   OR (start >= $inicio AND end <= $fin )
```

y con eso SI que coje el valor anteriormente comentado. Como digo, fallo mio al no contemplar el datetime completo.